# Get partial correlations matrix from pandas dataframe using spearman

Tags: python, pandas, correlation, pingouin

I want to obtain a matrix of partial correlatins (for all pairs), removing the effect of all other columns.

I am using `pingouin`, however the function

```
df.pcorr().round(3)
```

only works with `pearson correlation`.

Here is the code:

```
#!pip install pingouin

import pandas as pd 
import pingouin as pg

df = pg.read_dataset('partial_corr')
print (df.pcorr().round(3)) #LIKE THIS BUT USING SPEARMAN CORRELATION

OUT: #like this one except obtained with SPEARMAN 
         x      y    cv1    cv2    cv3
x    1.000  0.493 -0.095  0.130 -0.385
y    0.493  1.000 -0.007  0.104 -0.002
cv1 -0.095 -0.007  1.000 -0.241 -0.470
cv2  0.130  0.104 -0.241  1.000 -0.118
cv3 -0.385 -0.002 -0.470 -0.118  1.00
```

**Question**: how do I make a partial correlation matrix for a pandas dataframe, excluding covariance of all other columns using SPEARMAN?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the fact that a partial correlation matrix is simply a correlation matrix of residuals when the pair of variables are fitted against the rest of the variables (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_correlation#Formal_definition)).

You will need to get all the pairs - (`itertools.combinations` will help here) and fit linear regression (`sklearn`), get the ***spearman*** correlation on the residuals, then reshape the data to get the matrix.

Here is an example with the **Iris Dataset** that comes with `sklearn`.

```py
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from itertools import combinations
from sklearn import linear_model

#data
iris_data = load_iris()
iris_data = pd.DataFrame(iris_data['data'], columns=iris_data['feature_names'])

#get all the pairs of variables
xy_combinations = list(combinations(iris_data.columns, 2))
z = [[col for col in iris_data.columns if col not in xy] for xy in xy_combinations]
xyz_combinations = list(zip(xy_combinations, z))

#Compute spearman correlation
def part_corr(xyz):
    var1, var2, rest = *xyz[0], xyz[1]
    var1_reg = linear_model.LinearRegression().fit(iris_data[rest], iris_data[var1])
    var2_reg = linear_model.LinearRegression().fit(iris_data[rest], iris_data[var2])
    var1_res = iris_data[var1] - var1_reg.predict(iris_data[rest])
    var2_res = iris_data[var2] - var2_reg.predict(iris_data[rest])
    part_corr_df = pd.concat([var1_res, var2_res], axis=1).corr(method='spearman')
    return part_corr_df.unstack()

# Reshaping data for square matrix form
part_corr_df = pd.DataFrame(pd.concat(list(map(part_corr, xyz_combinations))), columns=['part_corr']).reset_index()
part_corr_matrix = part_corr_df.pivot_table(values='part_corr', index='level_0', columns='level_1')
part_corr_matrix
```

**Output**

```
level_1            petal length (cm)  petal width (cm)  sepal length (cm)  sepal width (cm)
level_0                                                                                    
petal length (cm)           1.000000          0.862649           0.681566         -0.633985
petal width (cm)            0.862649          1.000000          -0.303597          0.362407
sepal length (cm)           0.681566         -0.303597           1.000000          0.615629
sepal width (cm)           -0.633985          0.362407           0.615629          1.000000
```

Comment: thanks @Mortz, I can't get your code to run, is the correction: change iris_x to iris_data correct? (changed in z = [[col for col in iris_x.columns if col not in xy] for xy in xy_combinations])

Comment: Yeah - that's right. Sorry, missed that. Fixed that now

Comment: Thanks, the solution is great! It also really helps explaining what is happening (after spenidng some time trying to understand how the map, and combinations works..). Not super intuitive what happens with the residuas (especially when there are 2 confounding variables), i guess its a multiple linear regression? anyway thanks!

Comment: Yes - the idea is to get the residuals from regressing `VAR1` and `VAR2` against all the other variables, and then compute the correlation of the residuals. By regressing against a common set of confounding variables - you have removed any correlation these confounding factors have, and any remaining correlation in the residuals is over and above what is explained by the confounding factors.

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful if you could add the first n rows of your table to recreate your dataframe.

However, you can calculate the partial correlation using `pingouin.partial_corr()` by passing the `method='spearman'` parameter.

Take a look at the examples here
https://pingouin-stats.org/generated/pingouin.partial_corr.html

Comment: if you import the package pingouin, the dataframe is imported from it with: pg.read_dataset('partial_corr')